# Creating an array of strings from a text file

Tags: c, beginner

I'm try to create array of strings from a text file. I need a review from experienced programmers about my program. (MinGW gcc, Win7)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
FILE *file; 
char *fname = "lines.txt";
file = fopen(fname, "r");

if(file == NULL)
    printf("Can't read %s", fname);

char cbuff;

int nlines = 0; //counter of new lines
int chr = 0; //counter of chars (except new line char)

int maxlen = 0;
while( (cbuff = fgetc(file) - 0) != EOF )
{
    if(cbuff == '\n')
    {
        if (chr > maxlen)
        {
            maxlen = chr + 1;
        }

        chr = 0;
        nlines++;
    }

    else
    {
    chr++;
    }
}

printf( "lines: %d\nmax string len: %d\n\n", nlines, maxlen );
rewind(file);

char *list[nlines];

int buffsize = maxlen * sizeof(char);
char buff[buffsize];

int i = 0;
while(fgets(buff, buffsize, file))
{

    list[i] = malloc(strlen(buff) * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(list[i], buff);
    i++;
}

fclose(file);

int c = 0;
for(c; c < nlines; c++)
{
    printf( "%s", list[c] );
}
}//main
```

I'm trying to control size of array and items in array. Maybe I have errors somewhere, do not judge strictly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are truly coding in C then all variables should be declared at the start of the function. This has traditionally been how the C language worked and what C coders expect.

C has also traditionally not allowed for runtime declarations of array sizes. You should `malloc` the `list` variable.

If you initialize a loop variable then just omit it in the for loop definition. In other words don't do this:

```
for(c; c < foo; c++)
```

do this:

```
for( ; c < foo; c++)
```

A char is already a byte, no need to multiple `strlen` by `sizeof(char)`.

Personally I would move most of the logic into proper functions and out of `main`. It is just a good habit to get into.

Comment: The only standard of C that guarantees you the ability to have a variable-sized array (array size set at runtime) is C99. The newer standard, C11, allows compilers to implement but does not require it (you can tell by checking if a certain symbol is defined).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99 also allows inline variable declarations. I strongly disagree with @Sean; C99 is definitely C and cyan can use it if he wants to.

Comment: It is not guaranteed that a `char` is a `byte`; it is not guaranteed that `sizeof(char)==1`. If you want your code to be portable you **do** need to take `sizeof(char)`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're writing in C99. That's okay as long as your compiler supports it, but you should specify it, maybe with

```
#if __STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901L
// your code
#endif
```

Your `main()` routine should declare parameters for the argument count and argument list. My suggestion is that it check if there is an additional parameter and treat it as the filename if it exists, defaulting to `"lines.txt"` if there isn't one.

Then it should call another function with the string. (That other function opens the file, parses it, and returns a list as a `char**`, signalling an error [e.g. failure to open file] by returning `NULL`.) Finally `main()` should print out an error if the return was `NULL`, or if not, print the list, ideally by calling a second function.

As for the parsing function: It's not necessary to make two passes over the file. You can start out with your string buffer at a default size, and expand it as necessary (with `realloc()`) if your `fgets()` call ever doesn't terminate the string with `'\n'`. If you do still want to make two passes over the file, the passes should be in separate functions, to encapsulate the functionality (and of course a third function that calls the `fopen()` and `rewind()` and `fclose()` and passes the `FILE *` as a parameter).

In fact your method is potentially vulnerable to a race condition; if the underlying OS allows another process to modify the file being read at locations previous to the file pointer, you could end up crashing.

`int` is the wrong data type for `bufsize, chr, maxlen`. They're always going to be positive. Try `size_t`. Also, please pick a better variable name than `chr`.

You most definitely do need to take `sizeof(char)` when sizing the buffers.

What's the reason for the `- 0` in `cbuff = fgetc(file) - 0` ?

I suggest using `strncpy()` instead of `strcpy()`, especially since you know the max length already.